# How to create a ball that is able to jump using physics not animation?

Tags: animation, physics

I learned how to make a bouncing ball using soft body physics. Visually, I can use part of the ball movements so that it looks like as if the ball is a living creature that is able to jump.

Of course, I can do this using animation but it takes long time and effort.

I got an idea from a question here and I tried to export soft body physics as .mdd file and then I imported it back as shape keys but it didn't look great because there were some location movements and the ball is rotated although I didn't do any rotation.

I would like to ask about the best method or idea that enables me to use the physics system or any other easy system to create a jumping ball. Can I use force field or something similar to create the jump movement easily?

Thank you so much,

Comment: I think you would create collision objects that hit the soft body causing it to move and make the collision object invisible to the viewer.

Comment: @rob 1 sounds a good idea. Thanks :)